# Kyocera Net Viewer Cannot find / add printer

Tags: printer, network-printer

In our IT-Service we work with the Kyocera Net Viewer to keep an eye on our printers without checking the web interface for each printer seperately each time we want to verify the toner levels. However some of the printers aren't showing up anymore or disappeared for some reason. Trying to readd them via Express or Custom did not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Verified that the SNMP setting was turned on and noticed it was turned off. Turned it on did a restart of the Printers and suddenly it worked again.
Hope this helps others facing similar issues.